# how to make header disappear when scroll up and visible when scroll down?

Tags: react-native

I want a header like in google to keep when user scroll up header will slide up and right after user scroll down header will come down to a certain height

ref. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&hl=en_IN

header in this app is what I want

Comment: tell me in detail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide and show navbar in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389521/how-to-hide-and-show-navbar-in-react-native)

Comment: @HardikVirani this is not what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this nice example of a header that explains your use-case I guess

have a look

https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e